# Print value in column if criteria has been met in R

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement, mutate

I would like to create a column that would create a new column `New` that would print out the letter associated with that column (second table) if the condition has been met.

The example output looks like the `New` column below:

[image]

[image]

Reproducible example:

```
df <- data.frame(c(1,0,1), c(0,0,1), c(0,1,1), c(1,1,0), c(1,0,0))
names(df) <- paste0("C",1:5)

reftab <- data.frame(col1 = paste0("C",1:5), 
                     col2 = LETTERS[1:5])
```

Comment: plase share the data as code, not formated tables

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Please [do not post code or data in images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/2372064)

Answer (score 3):

I am sure there is a more elegant way, but in base R if you first use `apply` across rows to find the appropriate letters, then `lapply` to iterate through those results and paste them together, it should work.

Using these data:

```
df <- data.frame(c(1,0,1), c(0,0,1), c(0,1,1), c(1,1,0), c(1,0,0))
names(df) <- paste0("C",1:5)

reftab <- data.frame(col1 = paste0("C",1:5), 
                     col2 = LETTERS[1:5])
```

You can create the new column:

```
df$New <- lapply(apply(df, 1, \(x) reftab$col2[x == 1]),
                 paste, collapse = "")
```

Output:

```
#   C1 C2 C3 C4 C5 New
# 1  1  0  0  1  1 ADE
# 2  0  0  1  1  0  CD
# 3  1  1  1  0  0 ABC
```

Comment: I also have other columns in the dataset, is there a way to adjust the code to account for those?

Comment: Hi @ltong - happy to help! Could you clarify: do you want to select only certain columns to perform this action on, or do you just want to perform the action on *more* columns? Perhaps update the sample dataset in your question to clarify. We’ll figure this thing out :)

Answer (score 1):

We can transform reftab into a named vector with `tibble::deframe()`. then, subset their values by `cur_column()` inside mutate, and finally `paste0` everything together.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
library(purrr)

reftab <- deframe(reftab)

df |> 
    mutate(NEW = across(C1:C5,
                  \(x) if_else(x ==1,
                               reftab[cur_column()],
                               "")) |> 
    reduce(paste0))

# A tibble: 3 × 6
     C1    C2    C3    C4    C5 NEW  
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
1     1     0     0     1     1 ADE  
2     0     0     1     1     0 CD   
3     1     1     1     0     0 ABC
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another `dplyr` solution using `reftab` as a lookup table:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(New = paste(reftab$col2[which(c_across() == 1)], collapse = ""))

 C1    C2    C3    C4    C5 New  
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
1     1     0     0     1     1 ADE  
2     0     0     1     1     0 CD   
3     1     1     1     0     0 ABC
```

Comment: I also have other columns in the dataset, is there a way to adjust the code to account for those?

Comment: @ltong, for that, you can include a tidyselect statement inside `c_across`, as in `... which(c_across(C1:C5) ==1) ...`. TarJaes answer with empty `c_across` returns a depracation warning suggesting the need for a declared `cols` argumento to `c_across`

Answer (score 0):

We can do some matrix magic.
First transform `reftab` into a matrix of the same dimensions as `df`, then using `df` as a mask to select the correct names, and finally collapse by row, using `apply()`

```
df <- data.frame(c(1,0,1), c(0,0,1), c(0,1,1), c(1,1,0), c(1,0,0))
names(df) <- paste0("C",1:5)

reftab <- data.frame(col1 = paste0("C",1:5), 
                     col2 = LETTERS[1:5])

ne <- nc <- t(reftab[,rep(2, nrow(df))])
ne[] <- ""
ne[df==1] <- nc[df==1]
df$New <- apply(ne, 1, paste, collapse="")
df

  C1 C2 C3 C4 C5 New
1  1  0  0  1  1 ADE
2  0  0  1  1  0  CD
3  1  1  1  0  0 ABC
```